# At what depth are core fragments in Starbound?

Tags: starbound

I have been searching for a while but I haven't found a single one.  What depth can you find core fragments at?

Comment: If you need them for the early quest to repair the gate you should be able to find all you need in a mine not far from the initial beam down point. They'll appear in chests and defeating the boss there will drop a bunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Wiki](http://starbound.gamepedia.com/Core_Fragment_Ore):

> New players should expect to find Core Fragment Ore approximately 600-700 blocks below the surface.

It looks like you'll find core fragments between 600-700 blocks beneath the surface.

Comment: Core Fragment Ore is no longer in the game and has been replaced by (or renamed to) Core Fragments: http://starbounder.org/Core_Fragment